# Pretty Greek Problems for Emacs on Windows

Tags: emacs

I am trying to get http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PrettyGreek working for emacs 21.3.1 on Windows. I have put the following in my .emacs after downloading the European intlfonts from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/intlfonts/:

```
; ======= Pretty Greek Characters =======

(setq bdf-directory-list '("D:/emacs/intlfonts/European"))

(setq w32-bdf-filename-alist (w32-find-bdf-fonts bdf-directory-list))

(create-fontset-from-fontset-spec 
 "-*-fixed-medium-r-normal-*-16-*-*-*-c-*-fontset-bdf,
greek-iso8859-7:-*-*-medium-r-normal-*-16-*-*-*-c-*-iso8859-7" t)

(defun pretty-greek ()
  (let ((greek '("alpha" "beta" "gamma" "delta" "epsilon" "zeta" "eta" "theta" "iota" "kappa" "lambda" "mu" "nu" "xi" "omicron" "pi" "rho" "sigma_final" "sigma" "tau" "upsilon" "phi" "chi" "psi" "omega")))
    (loop for word in greek
          for code = 225 then (+ 1 code)
          do  (let ((greek-char (make-char 'greek-iso8859-7 code))) 
                (font-lock-add-keywords nil
                                        `((,(concatenate 'string "\\(^\\|[^a-zA-Z0-9]\\)\\(" word "\\)[a-zA-Z]")
                                           (0 (progn (decompose-region (match-beginning 2) (match-end 2))
                                                     nil)))))
                (font-lock-add-keywords nil 
                                        `((,(concatenate 'string "\\(^\\|[^a-zA-Z0-9]\\)\\(" word "\\)[^a-zA-Z]")
                                           (0 (progn (compose-region (match-beginning 2) (match-end 2)
                                                                     ,greek-char)
                                                     nil)))))))))

(add-hook 'lisp-mode-hook 'pretty-greek)
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'pretty-greek)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'pretty-greek)
(add-hook 'csharp-mode-hook 'pretty-greek)
```

However, when I try alpha beta gamma, I get the plus/minus character, superscript 2 and superscript 3. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: (1) Can you confirm that your Emacs version is 21.3.1 and not 23.1.1? The former is very old and the latter has much better support for unicode.

(2) On my Emacs 23.1.1 (on Mac OS X) your pretty-greek function works correctly. What happens if you evaluate `(insert (make-char 'greek-iso8859-7 255))` in your scratch buffer? The output of M-x describe-char on the inserted character might be also useful.

Comment: Yes, it is 21.3.1, maybe I should upgrade.

Doing (insert (make-char 'greek-iso8859-7 255)) gave me the alpha character in the scratch buffer. However, in actual programs, I am still getting strange characters. I think I shall just upgrade then.

Comment: Upgrading from 21 to 23 is probably not going to be painless (depends on how much you have customized Emacs already) and I'm not sure it will solve this problem without changing also other settings. But I can't think of any other possible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded from Emacs 21 to Emacs 23, and now the code is working fine. The transition was actually not too painful, and I would have needed to make the transition sometime anyway.